# How can I set a breakpoint in x64dbg to be triggered when a certain message is logged?

Tags: x64dbg, breakpoint

I am debugging a certain program and I need to stop execution when a certain debug message is logged using `OutputDebugStringA()`. How can I set a breakpoint for this?

Comment: Hi and welcome RE.SE. Logged how? There's a myriad of ways something can be logged and without knowing the method you can't expect advice where to look further. Thanks.

Comment: @0xC0000022L see my edit, it is using OutputDebugStringA.

Comment: I was able to get what I needed by setting x64dbg to break on debug messages, but that doesn't really answer my question. There should be away to get it to break only on certain messages.